# Can I use functions in Coq as constructors?

Tags: coq

I am trying to write a function to determine whether a number is odd and return it if it is, and not if it is not. In order to do this, I have matched the number with an odd function that returns true if it is odd. How can I use this as a constructor?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wazRM.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverlfow. Can you please be more specific by showing us the code snippet, it will help understand what you really are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, can you post your code inside your message as text rather than using screenshots? You can paste code in between backticks for instance, it should all be explained by the stackoverflow interface. In any case, what do you mean by using it as a constructor? You mean on the left-hand side of a `match`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any function as if it were a constructor in a `match` clause.  Only the constructors that appear in the declaration of a data type can be used in this fashion.  However, the `oddb` function returns a boolean, which is a data type defined by constructors, and thus you are allowed to match on its result:

```
match oddb n with
| true  => (* return something *)
| false => (* return something else *)
end
```

You can actually write this more verbose form as a regular if-then-else expression as found in other functional programming languages. When you write

```
if oddb n then
  (* return something *)
else 
  (* return something else *)
```

Coq automatically translates your input into the form above.

Comment: But the second form actually makes sense because the if function is dependant on whether or not (odd n) returns true or not, after which it would then proceed to do the appropriate action.

Comment: @Someone What is the "second form" you are talking about? The if expression I wrote? Yes, I agree that it makes sense. But if that's what you are talking about I don't understand your comment...